# YII displaying flash message when textbox value is updated

Tags: yii-extensions, yii-events

I have textbox in CGrid view that is generated from 
array(
            'header' => 'Points',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'name' => 'points',
            'value' =>  '($this->grid->owner->widget("application.extensions.jeditable.DsJEditableWidget", array(
                "model" => $this->grid->dataProvider,
                "name" => "points_".$data->orderinfoID,
                "value" => ($data->points),
                "jeditable_type" => "text",

```
        ),true))',
    ),
```

Now I want to display flash message when someone updates the point. In the flash message, user should be displayed old value(in the text box) and new value(newly entered value in the text box) in the top of the page.

Can anyone please tell me how can i achieve this.